# MYSQL - Query Combination

Tags: mysql

I have a table with this cols:

id, name and isWinner

I want to select an random winner and mark the selected row as a winner with isWinner.I select the winner with this sql query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE isWinner = '0' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

How can i update the isWinner field for selected winner?
And how can i set isWinner  for other cols of 0?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, to update the value of `isWinner`, you have to do like so:

```
`UPDATE table SET isWinner='1' WHERE id='X'`
```

X is the value of "id" that you retrieve from SELECT query.

To be honest, I don't understand the second question.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me try it :

```
update table set isWinner = 1 where id in 
(SELECT t.x from (SELECT id x FROM table 
WHERE isWinner = 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) t);
```